# django admin How do I change the order of the admin that came into the inlines?

Tags: django, admin

How do I change the order of the admin that came into the inlines?

[image]

I want to move that inlines admin field to under fields how to do that??

[image]

move inlines admin objects

here is my code

```
type here
inlines = [SpekaerSNSInline]
    list_display = ('id', 'name', 'display_sns_info', 'affiliation', 'speaker_image', 'order', 'pub_start_date', 'pub_end_date', 'created_at', 'updated_at')
```

I want to move inline block next to name
how can I do that please help

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the SpekaerSNSInline class from StackedInline ([refrence](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74438061/16508358)):

```
from django.contrib import admin

class SpekaerSNSInline(admin.StackedInline):
    ...
```